# RFC7231 - Content-Location must be verified by other means

Tags: http, security, http-headers, web-development-server, rfc

I'm reading through this RFC and got to a point that I don't see any information on the google-webs.  [Section 3.1.4.1. Identifying a Representation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.1) has a paragraph:

> If the response has a `Content-Location` header field and its field-value is a reference to a URI different from the effective request URI, then the sender asserts that the payload is a representation of the resource identified by the `Content-Location` field-value.  However, such an assertion cannot be trusted unless it can be verified by other means (not defined by this
> specification).

By what other means can this sort of representation be verified?

Answer (score 0):

The specification says more on this point a bit [further down](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2):

> If `Content-Location` is included in a `2xx` (Successful) response message and its field-value refers to a URI that differs from the effective request URI, then the origin server claims that the URI is an identifier for a different resource corresponding to the enclosed representation.  Such a claim can only be trusted if both identifiers share the same resource owner, which cannot be programmatically determined via HTTP.

So, you can trust the claim if the requested resource and the `Content-Location` resource have the same owner. How do you determine that?

One can imagine programmatic ways, such as checking the certificates presented by the corresponding URLs. In practice, though, I suspect this boils down to clients using simple rules to decide whom to trust. For example, if the `Content-Location` URI has the same domain as the resource, you might decide that the claim can be trusted.

Or, you might choose to implicitly trust any `Content-Location` claim made by certain whitelisted domains. For example, the Instagram app might trust any claim made by one of the Instagram servers.